# Scroll to end of element when images loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js

In a VueJS / Vuetify project, I have a div with a bunch of images in there.
I am using Vuetify images, meaning that they are lazy loaded.

I want the div to be scrolled to the end when displayed.

I have tried to scroll to the end when the component is mounted, but the images are not loaded, so scrolling to the end at that time doesn't work and just leaves the scroll position at 0.

I have tried to scroll to the end on a load event of the images, but then when the users scrolls back, new images load, bringing the user back to the end scroll.

I could add a timer to only scroll to the end after X ms, or to scroll on a image load, but only X number of times, or only for X ms, but those are hacky not reliable solutions.

What would be a clean and reliable way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have a count of how many images are going to load, or is it an infinite loader? if you have an Idea. you can user the load event on the v-img component to get an idea when an image is loaded and increment a value and compare it to the total number of images. once it reaches the number scroll down

Comment: I do have the list of images (thus the count). If I understand correctly, the problem with that is that when the list loads, I'll have the first images loaded, then move to the end, have the end images loaded, but the middle ones will never be loaded, and when displayed, they'll trigger the load and bring me back to the end

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution I've found is to scroll to the end on image loaded event, but I stop doing this when the last image is loaded (meaning that it's been displayed).

Comment: Thanks to @Prikesh Savla whose comment gave me the idea!

Comment: Happy to help!!